# jQuery Listener for Responsive Content

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive site and when the browser is greater than 500px wide, the .bio content is hidden, when it's on a phone, it shows.

Good thing is, it works but on when the page is loaded within those dimensions. So if my Firefox window is 400px and I resize the window to 900, the bio is still visible. If I load the page at 900px, the bio is hidden, as it should be.

How do I make jQuery fire again when the window size changes?

```
 $(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 500){
        $('.speakers li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.hide').toggle();
        });
    }else{
        $('.speakers li .bio').removeClass('hide');
    }
 });
```

Comment: Use `.resize()` event trigger: `$(window).resize(function(){});`

Comment: Media queries seem more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with CSS only using media queries, as suggested by MackieeE.

What prevented me from using media queries in the beginning was the content was being hidden by display:none. In that case, :hover is not available since there's nothing to hover over. Opacity was the trick.

I guess, with absolute positioning, you could also swap the z-index if you needed to click a link under the transparent div.

```
 .ease {-webkit-transition:All 0.15s ease; -moz-transition:All 0.15s ease; -o-transition:All 0.15s ease; -ms-transition:All 0.15s ease; transition:All 0.15s ease;}

 .bio {
    @media(min-width:@screen){
        opacity:0;
           /* more style */

    }

    @media(max-width:@phone){
        opacity:1;
           /* more style */
    }
 }

 .bio:hover {
    @media(min-width:@screen){
        .ease;
        opacity:1;
    }               
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could set up a boolean to detect if the user was smaller than the previous resize so
something like this should work

```
var run = true;
$(window).resize(function() {
   resizeEvt()
});
function resizeEvt()
{
  if($(window).width() > 500 && run){
        $('.speakers li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.hide').toggle();
        });
        run = false
    }else if ($(window).width() < 500 && !run){
        $('.speakers li .bio').removeClass('hide');
        run = true
    }
}
```

It will still run each time the user resizes but it shouldn't get as far as the hover parts.

and do what

I have not tested this code but the basic principle should work